# How to specify a geojson geometry crs for "internals" vector data?

Tags: geojson, coordinate-systems

I am writing a number of geojson files that represent non-georeferenced data. What is the correct way to specify the CRS? This actually works

"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.3:25832"

but I don't think I should use this, as I use this for proper geographic positioning of assets. The geometries in these files represent drawing showing the internals of substations, to obviously not be rendered in the same canvas as the geographic assets.

If I omit the CRS information or use "name": "local" I get the error message

"message": "Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID"

Comment: Which software library is giving that error message?

Comment: @LuísTavares I don't know, all I know is the json error message I get when I try to insert the data. Error looks like this `{
  "error": {
    "name": "error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what was needed was adding a record to table public.spatial_ref_sys to the target database. The added record looks like this, and all I had to do was use `"name" : "local:777777"` in the json data being inserted [image: added record]

This is good enough for my needs, as each substation will be rendered by a custom action which will only select and render records that are related to each specific substation container.